# In Clojurescript how can I get the String part of a UUID?

Tags: clojurescript

Whenever I print a cljs.core/UUID in Clojurescript I see:

```
#uuid "a7fc5304-010b-41fd-9e4e-4498cfb0e206"
```

: when all I want to see is :

```
"a7fc5304-010b-41fd-9e4e-4498cfb0e206"
```

: How can I access just the string part of a Clojurescript UUID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `str`:

```
(str #uuid "a7fc5304-010b-41fd-9e4e-4498cfb0e206")
```